# GCC cross compiler target library installation directory

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling

I am building a GCC 5.2.0 cross compiler with the following `./configure` command:

`../gcc-5.2.0/configure --prefix=/usr --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-myos-linux-gnu --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-sysroot=/myos --with-native-system-header-dir=/include`

So the build and host platforms are both `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`, and the target platform is `x86_64-myos-linux-gnu`.

In the build environment, I have a directory `/myos` (sub-directory of `/`) which contains the root filesystem for the target platform.

From what I understand, the GCC build procedure occurs in two major phases, the first one where the toolchain on the build environment is used to produce the GCC executables and suchlike, and the second phase where the just built executables are used to build various "target libraries" such as `libgcc` and `libstdc++`.

So after `make` and `make DESTDIR=... install`, I have:

```
usr/
usr/bin/
usr/include/
usr/lib/
usr/libexec/
usr/share/
usr/x86_64-myos-linux-gnu/
```

And from what I understand, `usr/x86_64-myos-linux-gnu/` contains files that are meant to be placed into the filesystem of the target platform (for instance the `.so` files of `libgcc` and `libstdc++`), however there are several problems:

1) by simply doing `make install`, the `usr/x86_64-myos-linux-gnu/` will not be placed into my target directory `/myos`.
2) if I `mv` the `usr/x86_64-myos-linux-gnu/` directory, it will not be consistent with the target library `.la` files. For instance, the file `usr/x86_64-myos-linux-gnu/lib64/libtsan.la` contains the line:
`dependency_libs=' -lpthread -ldl '/usr/x86_64-myos-linux-gnu/lib/../lib64/'/libstdc++.la -lm'`
which is expressing an absolute path to `libstdc++`, but will simply not be there if I blatantly `mv` the `usr/x86_64-myos-linux-gnu/` directory.

Neither the top-level `./configure --help` nor the [GCC install docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/) seem to state any way to change the path of the `usr/x86_64-myos-linux-gnu/` directory. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> And from what I understand, usr/x86_64-myos-linux-gnu/ contains files that are meant to be placed into the filesystem of the target platform

No, you have built a cross-compiler, so the installed files are meant to live on the *host* platform, not the target.

> 1) by simply doing make install, the usr/x86_64-myos-linux-gnu/ will not be placed into my target directory /myos.

Correct. The files live in the GCC installation tree, not the sysroot. That way they will still be found by the cross-compiler, so everything still works.

Typically the sysroot (in your case `/myos`) would not actually be the root FS of the target, it would be a copy of the same files as are installed on the target, so installing GCC's libraries into that sysroot would not really help, because they wouldn't appear on the target.

If you want those libraries on the target you need to install them there yourself.

Comment: Well for instance, if I build a C++ program with the cross compiler, it will link against libstdc++.so found on the host platform. But if I then try to run that program inside the target platform, libstdc++.so won't be found -- so do I need to build GCC a second time with a different "--prefix", just for the target libraries which really were built the first time around? If so. seems kind of crude to say the least.

Comment: No, just copy the libraries to the target machine. You just can't use `make install` to do that. Like I said, "If you want those libraries on the target you need to install them there yourself."

Comment: I understand that is an option, but like I say even if it "just works" it does not seem the appropriate way because there are a lot of ".la files within the "usr/x86_64-myos-linux-gnu/lib/" directory that express absolute paths. There would be little to no harm in there being a way to just change the default path of the "usr/x86_64-myos-linux-gnu/" directory -- as they are files that were built in phase 2, where the just-built cross-compiler is used to build them -- so they are very much appropriately located within the target platform.